# Conjecture: If $A^\prime$ is outside the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$, then $\triangle A^\prime BC$ has a larger circumradius

Tags: geometry

While solving a few problems, I came across a property of triangle. It looks simple, but I am not able to prove it. Simply stating it:

> **Conjecture.** Given $\triangle ABC$ and its circumcircle, consider a point $A^\prime$ outside the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. The circumradius of $\triangle A^\prime BC$ is greater than the circumradius of $\triangle ABC$.

Note: I am not sure whether the statement is completely correct or not. It's just an observation.

Comment: Without additional conditions, the conjecture is false. In particular, it's possible that $A^\prime$ is outside $\bigcirc ABC$ while also $A$ is outside $\bigcirc A^\prime BC$, with distinct circumradii, so one radius is greater, but one is smaller.

Comment: What might be the additional conditions?

Comment: Just to overcome the problem I noted, you need to require $A$ to be inside $\bigcirc A^\prime BC$. Whether that's enough to guarantee the conjecture ... I haven't really thought about it.

Comment: If your intent is to guarantee a larger circle, you could use this: On the side of $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ containing the *major arc* $\stackrel{\frown}{BC}$, point $A^\prime$ must lie *outside* $\bigcirc ABC$; on the side containing the *minor arc*, $A^\prime$ must lie *inside*. (If the case of semicircles, $A^\prime$ can lie inside or outside.) With this formulation, it doesn't matter where $A$ is relative to $\bigcirc A^\prime BC$. (Note that $A^\prime$ *on* $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ determines a line, which you may want to consider not-a-circle or else a circle of infinite radius.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. Consider a triangle $ABC$ with an obtuse angle at $A$, and let $D$ be a point further back from $A$ so that $\angle CDB$ is right. Since $\angle CDB < \angle CAB$, $D$ is outside the circle that contains $A,B,C$. Then the circumcircle of triangle $DBC$ is smaller than that of $ABC$.
Why? Because $BC$ is a diameter of the circumcircle of $DBC$, but not of the circumcircle of $ABC$.

Now, if that were an acute triangle we started with...

Comment: What can happen if it an acute angled triangle?

Comment: Add the condition that it's an acute triangle, and the modified conjecture is true. Hint: Law of Sines.

Comment: yes i got it thanks. Thanks

Comment: Any idea how to extend it to obtuse angled triangles?